# Экранирование символов при выводе строк на консоль

Tags: java

```
public class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("It's Windows path: \"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin"); 
    System.out.println("It's Java string: "\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\bin");
  }
}
```

Никак не пойму как экранируются кавычки при выводе на консоль

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знак `\` экранирует спецсимволы, такие как `n`,`r`,`"`,`\` и т.д.. этот знак говорит нам о том, что мы не закрываем первую кавычку `"It's`, а печатаем в текст кавычку. В результате чего получаем текст `It's Windows path: "C:`

P.s. в путьях не хватает знака `\`, чтобы экранировать опять же

**UPD**

[Линк](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) на Escape символы, требующие экранирование . Спасибо за это @ArtemKonovalov

Comment: линк на спеку где перечислены escape символы требующие экранирование http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6

Comment: System.out.println("It's Windows path: \"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\""); 
        System.out.println("It's Java string: \"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\bin\""); Вот я исправил но все равно компилятор на меня ругается

Comment: @HelloGoogle должно быть ` System.out.println("It's Windows path: \"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\bin\"");` так как вы не экранируйте слэш (`\`). то есть если хотите в пути увидеть знать слэша, то должны два слеша ставить. как в этом комментарий

Comment: System.out.println("It's Windows path: \"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\bin\""); 
System.out.println("It's Java string: \"C:\\\Program Files\\\Java\\\jdk1.7.0\\\bin\""); - я так полагаю что и \ - слеш надо экранировать? Но не ничего не выходит.

Comment: (``) - это для чего?

Comment: System.out.println("It's Windows path: \"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\bin\"");
        System.out.println("It's Java string: \\\"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Java\\\\jdk1.7.0\\\\bin\\\""); - вот ответ. Но почему нужно экранировать так же и слеш не пойму.

Comment: @HelloGoogle символы `` позволяют выделить кусок текста в этих кавычках, как код. см примеры в ответах. 

вы пишете \\\ - это означает \ - экранирует следующий знак. второй знак тоже \, поэтому \\ будет появляться как строка с одной \. то есть "C:\\c" == в output-е C:\c. Дальше вы снова пишете \- снова экранируете следующий знак, 4-й знак тут P, но нет спецсимвола \P. поэтому получаете ошибку. я в комментариях уже привел вам работающий пример с двумя кавычками

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Теперь я понял свою ошибку :D

Answer (score 3):

В этом, близком к правильному написанию строкового литерала, предложении вы забыли вставить закрывающую кавычку

```
 System.out.println("It's Java string: \"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\bin\"");
```

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы ставите кавычки `"`, то среда разработки думает, что вы закрыли строку, передаваемую в `System.out.println()`. Чтобы написать "кавычки в кавычках" воспользуйтесь управляющими последовательностями. Перед кавычками пишите знак `\`. Например

```
System.out.println("Hello, \"world\"!");
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Hello, "world"!
```

Answer (score 2):

System.out.println("It\'s Windows path: \"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\"");
        System.out.print("It\'s Java string: \\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\bin\\"");

Comment: Чем ваш ответ отличается от, на пример, @diana?

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("It\'s Windows path: \"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\bin\"");
System.out.println("It\'s Java string: \\\"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Java\\\\jdk1.7.0\\\\bin\\\"");
```

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ.